# Java: RegEx Multiple Matches in Same 'fragment'

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx that would capture both instance of 'csv' delimited by commas in the string "csv,csv,csv,csv" and replace with "xml".

So my output would be "csv,xml,xml,csv".

The problem I'm running into is that my RegEx only captures the first instance of csv, and since the 'comma' at the end of the first match would also be the first delimiter of the second match, it doesn't get captured.

RegEx = ",csv," (pretty simple example).

Example 2:

RegEx = "(,dog,)"

Input "dog,dog,dog,dog"

Output "dog,cat,cat,dog"

Edit: I found what I was looking for, using lookahead and lookbehind.
RegEx = "(?<=,)dog(?=,)" would do the trick.

Comment: Rule #1 of dealing with CSV is NOT to attempt to use regex.  CSV syntax is not regular.  Use an existing CSV library like OpenCSV.  A lot of work has gone into writing and debugging it, and you cannot hope to replicate it yourself without a huge amount of work.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the actual content, say 'csv', but the case where the last delimiter of one match would also be the first delimiter of the next match. A better example could be "dog,dog,dog,dog" replaced to "dog,cat,cat,dog' when looking for RegEx = "(,dog,)"

Comment: Please don't edit your *question* with a solution - post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use look arounds, which assert, but don't consume:

```
String replaced = str.replaceAll("(?<=,)csv(?=,)", "xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of lookaround:

replace

```
(?<=,)xml(?=,)
```

with

```
csv
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/ft7SQT/1